# What is Shutdown Cause -108?

Tags: macos, shutdown

My rMBP 15" just shut down by itself when idling, screen turned off.

When I rebooted it, I checked the Console to see why it shut down, and found this message: `10/27/12 1:21:36.000 AM kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: -108`

What is Shutdown Cause -108?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.macwizard.com/errors.html) page, Shutdown Cause -108 seems to be due to a lack of memory.

Comment: The Title of that Page is "Macintosh System Error Codes Explained (Pre OS X)", so i doubt the explanation would apply to this case.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't see it.

Comment: Whilst [Mac OS System Error Codes: 0 to -261](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618) is archived by Apple, and describes *error codes* (not *shutdown causes*), I should not rush to dismiss its relevance. Compare with a recent [answer about error code -60](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111607/8546), which does appear to correspond with *<Debug>: Previous Shutdown Cause: -60* …

Answer (score 0):

A negative shutdown code, may indicate a hardware problem (not necessary memory, because precise meaning of the codes is not publicly documented). You may try [reseting your SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). If this won't help, you should back up your data and take it to the repair.