# What is shutdown cause -60?

Tags: macos, shutdown

Since installing Mavericks on my 2010 MBP, it seems to be giving me the spinning beach ball often. I think I may need a new HDD, as Disk Utility cannot repair it, but I also get this error:

```
Nov 21 20:33:38 COMPUTERNAME kernel[0] <Debug>: Previous Shutdown Cause: -60
```

Comment: Please add detail of what was reported by Disk Utility. You may find a record in `/var/log/fsck_hfs.log` …

Answer (score 2):

**-60 is badMDBErr (bad master directory block error)**

It indicates that there is something wrong with the drive, and Disk Utility not being able to repair the drive supports this. Back up your data, erase using Disk Utility and reinstall OS X.

[OS X Shutdown Causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/)

Answer (score 0):

> Shutdown Cause: -60

This shutdown code is usually related to bad master directory block (badMDBErr).

So you can try to:

- Run *First Aid* from the Disk Utility to check your HD (or `fsck` from Safe mode).
- Reset [the System Management Controller (SMC)](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295).

If above won't help, you are advised to back up your data, erase the disk and reinstall OS X.

<sup>See: [Are OS X shutdown cause and sleep cause numbers listed/explained anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781)</sup>

---

The perceptible symptoms may include:

- Fail to share or synchronize the Mac files.
- Hard drive issues.
- Sometimes peripheral devices may seem to be disturbed.
- Poor performance of the system in terms of speed, especially.
- Corruption of Mac files without any perceptible warning (e.g. faulty registry entries, file system corruption).
- Mac starts freezing every now and then.
- Occurrence of the error message like “file not found”, “access denied”.
- Operating system malfunctioning

So the real cause could related to different reasons and factors, such as:

- The *[-60] badMDBErr-bad* master directory block can occur due to the fact that a file or a program that your system just called upon has been damaged.
- The problem may also appear if a system file has turned corrupt.
- Due to the fact that you accidently deleted system file…oops…a human mistake.
- When a program was getting executed and suddenly your Mac was turned off due to power cut, or anything like that, the file or program under consideration fail to mount resulting in the [-60] badMDBErr-bad master directory block in Mac.
- This error can also take place if you are sharing file(s) through unsupported platforms.
- Incorrectly modified BIOS settings.

Source: [[-60] badMDBErr-bad master directory block Error](http://www.howtofixmacerrors.com/solved-60-badmdberr-bad-master-directory-block-error/) at howtofixmacerrors site